# .module.css или .css?

Tags: css, reactjs

Какое расширение стилевых файлов для React лучше и в каких ситуациях? .module.css и .css

Comment: И то и другое имеет расширение **css**

Comment: Это я понимаю, но есть какая-то принципиальная разница?

Comment: Если и то и другое одно и то же, то разницы нет. Может у вас визуально есть принципиальная разница, как те или иные файлы со стилями называются... Одним словом, это просто предпочтения в названии файлов

Comment: @SwaD, в зависимости от настроек - разница есть: `.module.css` - компилируется как css module, и к именам классов добавляется `hash` чтобы они не пересекались с такими же именами в других файлах. Просто `.css` - остается как есть

Comment: [Adding a CSS Modules Stylesheet](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если тебе нужно использовать css файл в какой-то определенной области, тогда module.css. А если должна быть видимость по всему сайту - тогда просто .css

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от настроек может быть следующая разница:

1. `.module.css` - компилируется как css-module, и к именам классов добавляется `hash`, чтобы они не пересекались с такими же именами в других файлах.
2. Просто `.css` - остается как есть, классы доступны глобально, но могут быть конфликты, когда в разных компонентах одному свойству присваиваются разные значения.

Подробнее в [Adding a CSS Modules Stylesheet](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)